# Overlay items adding more than two items using *1e6

Tags: android

Adding overlay items in android i want to add overlay items in the map view !! so here i go

```
public void addOverLays(){

    String [] coordinates = {"30.084262490272522","31.33625864982605" ,"30.084123015403748", "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"};
    double lat = 30.084262490272522, lat2 = 51.5002,lat3=30.084123015403748;
    double log = 31.33625864982605, log2 = -0.1262,log3=31.337149143218994;

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));


   p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6));

   p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1000000), (int) (log3 * 1000000));

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);
   drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dotred);

    drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

        itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this);        
    itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);    
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
   OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");
    OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over3);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
 mc.setZoom(17); 
 //mc.animateTo(p);
}
```

>

<<
but the p3 the third over lay item force the application to close <   p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1000000), (int) (log3 * 1000000));> seem an error in 1000000 ! but i already use 1e6 and 1E6 but they are floating and 1000000 is integer so what to do ?!
and here is the errors appear in the DDMS >>

```
04-25 00:27:17.370: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItemsAtLocation(ItemizedOverlay.java:617)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItemAtLocation(ItemizedOverlay.java:586)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.handleMotionEvent(ItemizedOverlay.java:498)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTouchEvent(ItemizedOverlay.java:572)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTouchEvent(OverlayBundle.java:63)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:620)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:851)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:811)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:811)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:811)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:811)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1758)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1202)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1742)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1549)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
04-25 00:27:17.390: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @lolo: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close".

Comment: yup i knew that the problem is that p3 and the *1000000 ; due to its an integer not float what shall i do ?

Comment: the problem is touch event when i add the 3 items and touch the  screen to make zoom it force close Despite when it only 2 items its show the zoom option and zoom in and out normally ! what is the solution ?

Comment: @lolo: Why don't you use p3=new GeoPoint((int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6)); ???

Comment: @ MisterSquonk i guess it must done only once and i did 1e6 and 1E6 !! so that the problem ! and its touch screen problem

Comment: @lolo: 1e6 and 1E6 are constant values representing the number 1000000 in 'double' form. Both 1e6 and 1E6 mean the same thing and you can use them as many times as you like not just one time.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting?

This line:

```
itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over3);
```

should probably be:

```
itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);
```

Comment: i cant believe that i'm so this stupid ! really thank you so much , and sorry for your time . thank in advance